# java-how to convert an object (store char)type to integer

Tags: java, type-conversion

java-how to convert an object (store char)type to integer
following is part of my code
in method print where has ❤❤❤❤❤ sign where I need value of testSample.pop() in order to finish my method. But since the variable it returned is an object type, I can not cast it, and then how can I convert it to an integer. thank you for the help.

```
public class Stack {
public static int capacity = 100;
private Object S[];
private int top = -1;
public Stack(){
    this(capacity);
}
public Stack(int cap){
    capacity = cap;
    S = new String[capacity];
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return(top<0);
}
public int size(){
    return(top+1);
}
public void push(Object x){
    if(size() == capacity) throw new StackException("Stack overflow");
    S[++top] = x;
}
public Object pop(){
    Object x;
    if(isEmpty()) throw new StackException("Stack is empty");
    x=S[top];
    S[top--] = null;
    return x;
}
public void print(String sign){
    Stack testSample = new Stack();
    int num1 = 0; int num2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sign.length(); i++){
        char c = sign.charAt(i);
        if(c == '('){
            testSample.push(c); 
        }
        else if (c == ')'){
            num1 = ❤❤❤❤❤❤
            num2 = c;
            for(int j = num1+1; j < num2; j++){
                char a = sign.charAt(i);
                if(!(c == '('||c == ')'))
                System.out.print(a);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating your own stack type when Java provides a perfectly good one? And what would you expect to happen if someone pushed a non-integer onto the stack? If you *require* integers on the stack, you should make that the type for push and pop...

Comment: Try `num1 = Integer.parseInt(testSample.pop().toString());`

Comment: I want to store Blurglecruncheons in your stack. There is no way to represent a Blurglecruncheon as an integer, so there is something wrong with your design...

Answer (score 0):

As it is returning an Object, convert it into String and then use Integer.parse to cast it to Integer:

```
Integer.parseInt(testSample.pop().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you push Character values to the stack, even though it pops out as an Object, you should be able to simply cast it to Character and then get the int value related to the Character.

```
Integer.valueOf((Character) obj); //obj is the value popped up
```